# Why is app.put() not updating documents in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, routes, ejs

I am trying to implement a form in an ejs file that, upon clicking a button, the "likes" attribute of a displayed document from my mongoDB collection is set to 0 via a "PUT" request. However, the document in question does not update and I do not know why.

The console does not display any errors.

```html
<!--This file is called "home.ejs"-->

<!--This is to display the document:-->
      <form action="/" method="GET">
            <h3> MONGO FETCHED: </h3>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span><%= numbers.usertext %></span>
                    <h3><%= numbers.likes%></h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>

<!--Upon clicking the button "upvote", it is suppose to tell index.js 
to update the "likes" attribute of the displayed document and set it to 0. 
However, it does nothing-->
        <div>
            <form action="/" method="PUT">
                <button id="upvote" type="submit">upvote</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

In my index.js file, I fetch a random document in my collection to display to the user. I have defined body-parser, so I know that is not the problem.

```js
MongoClient.connect(DBconnection, { useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(client => {
    console.log(`Connected to database: ${database}`);
    console.log(`Connected to table: ${table}`);

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set('views', './views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    const db = client.db(database);
    const collection = db.collection(table);    
            
    const w = db.collection(table).find().limit(-1).skip(R-1).next()
    //variable R has been defined as a random number

//This gets the fetched random document, w, and then renders it on home.ejs
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        w
        .then(numbers => {
          res.render("home.ejs", { numbers: numbers});
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    })

//This route submits information into the database from a file separate from home.ejs
    app.post(`/${table}`, (req, res) => {
        collection.insertOne(req.body)
        .then(result => {
            res.redirect('/')
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    });

//This is suppose to update the attribute "likes" from the document w (as defined earlier)
//and set it to 0. However, this code block does not do so.
    app.put(`/${table}`, (req, res) => {
        db.collection(table).findOneAndUpdate({w}, {$set: {likes: "0"} })
        .then(result => {
            console.log("updated succesfully");
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
    });


});
```

I would appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: since it doesn't update, do you get back an error instead?

Comment: No, no error is received in the console

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with the code.

1. In your EJS file you cannot have a form method of PUT. Valid methods for HTML forms are GET and POST.
2. You don't have a route to handle your form submission.
3. Express with EJS is a server-side rendered application architecture. Once you click submit in your bottom form, the page will be refreshed. If you don't want a full page refresh, then you'll need to do some client-side JavaScript.

I would suggest going through an express form tutorial.